# How can I use subclass in java that I can print two different length of String?

Tags: java

Here is a big project, so I can just show you part of the code.
There are two different plan of membership: standard and family. When the member is standard membership, the information of that member contains(name, dob, expire date, location), but when the member's plan is family, the information of that member contains(name, dob, expire date, location, guest-pass remaining) Which means their gonna have one more element. But they have been stored in the same database. And my question is how can I print them.
The out put should be

```
Carl Brown, DOB: 10/7/1991, Membership expires 3/31/2023, Location: PISCATAWAY, 08854, MIDDLESEX
Jerry Brown, DOB: 6/30/1979, Membership expires 12/28/2022, Location: EDISON, 08837, MIDDLESEX, (Family) guest-pass remaining: 1
```

But I only get

```
Carl Brown, DOB: 10/7/1991, Membership expires 3/31/2023, Location: PISCATAWAY, 08854, MIDDLESEX
Jerry Brown, DOB: 6/30/1979, Membership expires 12/28/2022, Location: EDISON, 08837, MIDDLESEX
```

Here is my code
**Member**

```
public class Member implements Comparable<Member> {
private String fname;
private String lname;
private Date dob;
private Location location;
private Date expire = Date.getEXP();

@Override
public String toString() {
    String info = String.format("%s %s, DOB: %s, Membership expires %s, Location: %s", fname, lname, dob,
            expire, location);
    return info;
}

public Member(String fname, String lname, Date dob, Location location) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.location = location;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public Date getDOB() {
    return dob;
}

public Date getEXP() {
    return expire;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
```

}

And it asked me to use subclass to get a Family plan,so I write this
**Family**

```
public class Family extends Member{
private int gpRemaining;
public Family(String fname, String lname, Date dob, Location location, int gpRemaining) {
    super(fname, lname, dob, location);
    this.gpRemaining = gpRemaining;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String info = String.format("%s %s, DOB: %s, Membership expires %s, Location: %s, (Family) " +
            "guest-pass remaining:" + " %d", this.getFname(), this.getLname(), this.getDOB(),
            this.getEXP(), this.getLocation(), gpRemaining);
    return info;
}

public int getGpRemaining() {
    return gpRemaining;
}
```

}

And here is the **MemberDatabase** print method:

```
public class MemberDatabase {
private Member[] mlist;
private int size = 0;
private int capacity = 4;

public MemberDatabase() {
    mlist = new Member[capacity];
}


public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

private int find(Member member) {
    for (int indexOfMember = 0; indexOfMember < size; indexOfMember++) {
        if(mlist[indexOfMember].equals(member)) {
            return indexOfMember;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private void grow() {
    capacity += 4;
    mlist = Arrays.copyOf(mlist, capacity);
}


public boolean add(Member member) {
    if (find(member) != -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            return false;
        }
        if (size != 0 && (find(member) != -1)) {
            return false;
        }
        mlist[size++] = member;
        if (size >= capacity) {
            grow();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean remove(Member member) {
    if (member == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int indexOfMember = find(member);

    if (indexOfMember != -1) {
        mlist[indexOfMember] = mlist[--size];
        mlist[size] = null;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Print the original membership database
 */

public void print() {
    if (size == 0) {
        System.out.println("Member database is empty!");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("\n-list of members-");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.println(mlist[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("-end of list-\n");
}
```

Here is the **add**method which Add the members:
The input is like

> A Carl Brown, 10/7/1991, Piscataway

> AF Jerry Brown 6/30/1979 Edison

```
case A means this member has standard membership which means the 
output should be 
> Carl Brown, DOB: 10/7/1991, Membership expires 3/31/2023, Location: PISCATAWAY, 08854, MIDDLESEX


public void run() {
    System.out.println("Gym Manager running...");
    String input;
    String[] inputs;
    creatClass();
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        input = scan.nextLine();
        inputs = input.split("\\s");
        if (input.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }
        switch (inputs[0]) {
            case "A" -> A(inputs);
            case "AF" -> AF(inputs);

private void A(String[] input) {
    String[] dobDate = input[3].split("/");
    Date dob = new Date(Integer.parseInt(dobDate[0]), Integer.parseInt(dobDate[1]), Integer.parseInt(dobDate[2]));
    if (isValidLocation(input[4])) {
        if (isValidDOB(dob)) {
            Member member = new Member(input[1], input[2], dob, Location.valueOf(input[4].toUpperCase()));
            if (member !=null) {
                if (!database.add(member)) {
                    System.out.println(input[1] + " " + input[2] + " is already in the database.");
                } else System.out.println(input[1] + " " + input[2] + " added.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

/**
Case AP means that the member has family membership and the output should be

> Jerry Brown, DOB: 6/30/1979, Membership expires 12/28/2022, Location: EDISON, 08837, MIDDLESEX, (Family) guest-pass remaining: 1
> */

```
private void AP (String[] input) {
    String[] dobDate = input[3].split("/");
    Date dob = new Date(Integer.parseInt(dobDate[0]), Integer.parseInt(dobDate[1]), Integer.parseInt(dobDate[2]));
    if (isValidLocation(input[4])) {
        if (isValidDOB(dob)) {
            Family member = new Family(input[1], input[2], dob, Location.valueOf(input[4].toUpperCase()), 1);
            if (member !=null) {
                if (!database.add(member)) {
                    System.out.println(input[1] + " " + input[2] + " is already in the database.");
                } else System.out.println(input[1] + " " + input[2] + " added.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: `toString` should have no arguments. Don't declare one and just use `this` in the method.

Comment: `public String toString(Family m1) ` <- what is the point of the argument `Family m1`? An object knows about itself so if you want a Family object to print information about itself there is no need to pass any argument. You should override the `toString()` method, meaning override it with the same method signature as the superclass and not adding any arguments.

Comment: So how can I use this in a subclass?

Comment: Same way you use `this` anywhere. I don't really get your question.

Comment: I mean like because this is a subclass, so I need to use "super" to get the data from super class. How I can use like this.fname = fname? fname is private in Member class

Comment: If you want to get `fname` you can just use the public getter you defined for that field: `this.getFname()`. Not sure however why you want to do `this.fname = fname` in the subclass. I thought you just wanted to print already existing information not set fields.....

Comment: Yeah I tried, but the result is also :Jerry Brown, DOB: 6/30/1979, Membership expires 1/10/2023, Location: EDISON, 08837, MIDDLESEX  WHich means it is also wrong...

Comment: Can you share how you actually fill `Member[] mlist`? If printing contents of it doesn't use the `toString()`method if your `Family` subclass this would mean the objects you put into that array aren't objects of that subclass.

Comment: because you declare and create an object of class Member, if you want to create instance of class Family you should use `mlist = new Family[capacity];`

Comment: I will add the add method

Comment: I dont think I can change mlist = new Family[capacity] because both Family and Member are put together

Comment: @BraVo consider creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows your problem. Unfortunately the 2 add methods you added to your question aren't enough information as I have no idea how you call them. An example that is complete and we can run to see the problem ourselves would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: I have add more information, please check

Comment: @BraVo The code still isn't a complete example and  doesn't show how those methods `private void A(String[] input)` and `private void AP (String[] input)` are called. It might as well be that only the first one is actually called and that is your problem but since I don't have the information to determine that I can't really do more than guess, which isn't helpful. Hence why I asked for a complete example.

Comment: Your class code works in theory, see https://ideone.com/0sXqCB - whatever the issue is, it's probably not the way you subclass / override toString (that by the way would be a reproducible example)

Comment: Here I think is the full information, please check

Comment: `case "AF" -> AF(inputs);` There is no method called `AF` in the code you posted. The code would therefor not compile.

Comment: again you call the toString method as Member hence the Family toString method will never be called if you wanted to you can try casting it first to Family before you print the toString method, and you can also check first before casting it to Family wether the object is instance of Family or not